# spotlight search for folder within finder

Tags: macos, finder

I hit cmd-shift-g for go to folder, but I have to type the full path

Is there some way for me to search a folder name and go straight there?

Like how automjump/z etc. work in the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Yep, just search for what you want in the top right of the finder window. As long as you are not in [gallery view mode](https://www.macworld.com/article/3284366/article.html), have your mac updated to the latest version, and have made sure the application is searching the whole mac, it should show a section called folders. There, it will show all of the folders that match your search.

[image: Picture that shows what I mean]

Comment: You might want to mention that you can click the [+] button under the Search box to refine the search criteria. Also, I've found that the search does not always bring up system folders, e.g. searching for Library doesn't always bring up `/Library`, `~/Library`, `/System/Library`, etc.

Comment: No, this shows folders in a weird order (doesn't seem to be based on most frequently used), and it's annoying to distinguish between folders of the same name. It's also a very multi-step procedure: start searching, change to "This Mac", change to filter for folders only, then click through the results until I find the one with the right path. This solution sucks.

Comment: Well, I don't know any other way besides getting a 3rd party file manager...

Comment: @theonlygusti You could create an _Automator_ service and write a script that does what you want, then redirect the shortcut key you’re currently using to the service.  I think the transition would be seamless.  You would need to be clear with what the scope of the folder search should be, and what to do if there’s multiple folders with the same name.

Comment: @CJK I want it "like how automjump/z etc. work". Making a new service is annoying: is there a way to track what folders I visit  with Finder?

Comment: You're going to have to explain _how_ `automjump/z` works for those, like myself, who have not used it—you'll probably get more help when people know precisely what you want. _"is there a way to track what folders I visit with Finder"_ Finder stores the 10 most recent folders visited. To obtain them, you still need to do some scripting, so if you find making a service annoying, then you probably don't have very good odds of achieving what you want. It's up to you, I suppose: depends which you find more annoying: creating the service, or continue to type full folder paths.